# Basic statistics problem

Tags: statistics

i have a small statistics problem:

The time spent by students to solve an exam, following a normal distribution, has a mean of 80 minutes, and a standard deviation of 20 minutes.

.. and asks:

What's the minimum time that 30% of the students spent on it?

Can anyone help me finding the way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: This must be a homework. If it is, please read on [how to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) on this site.

Comment: This should be one of the "general" types of questions asked for in the meta. I can't think of how to phrase it in a general way though that would be recognizable to someone who'd ask it...

Comment: This question (and its variants) has been hashed and rehashed any number of times on stats.SE. I would vote to close, if I could.

Comment: It's not homework, i'm just practicing on solving statistics problems for my exam.

Comment: @Inside: For future reference, Sasha's comment (and associated link) still apply. The more effort you put into providing context for your question, the more likely people will make the effort to provide a nice response. In this case, David has already provided essentially the complete answer.

Comment: Yes, i read the homework section, and i guess i should had followed that guideline. I just didn't know about it. Next time i need i'm going to follow the rules. Thanks a lot people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=$the time spent by a student on the test. $X$ has normal distribution with mean 80 and standard deviation 20. 
You need to solve $$P[X>a]=.3$$
Passing to the  standard normal distribution,   need to solve
 $$P[{X-80\over 20}>{a-80\over20} ]=.3,$$
or,
$$
[Z>{a-80\over20} ]=.3
$$
where $Z$ is the standard normal variable. You need to do a "reverse lookup": go to a table/calculator for the CDF of the standard normal and find the value $z$ with $P[Z>z]=.3$. Call this $z_3$. Then set
$$
z_3= {a-80\over20}
$$
and solve for $a$.